# Working on three tier in c# but my insert query is not working

Tags: c#

access layer:

```
public bool AddStudent(string busStudentFullName, string busStudentFatherName)
{
    con = new SqlCeConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "data source = C:\\Users\\hasni\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\UniversityManagementSystem\\UniversityManagementSystem\\UniversityDB.sdf";
    con.Open();

    ds1 = new DataSet();
    //DataTable t = new DataTable();
    // string sql = "SELECT * from AdminPassword where Admin Name ='" + AdminNameLogintextBox.Text + "' and Password='" + PasswordLogintextBox.Text + "'";
    //string qry = "SELECT * FROM Students";

    // string sql = "SELECT * from AdminPassword where Admin Name ='" + AdminNameLogintextBox.Text + "' and Password='" + PasswordLogintextBox.Text + "'";
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Students";


    da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(sql, con);
    //da = new SqlCeDataAdapter();

    //DataTable t = new DataTable();
    //da.Fill(t);
    da.Fill(ds1, "Students");


    //string userNameDB = Convert.ToString(ds1.Tables[0]);
    // return userNameDB;

    con.Close();
   // string busStudentFullName;
    //string busStudentFatherName;
    string sql2 = "INSERT INTO Students (Student Full Name,Student Father Name) Values('"+ busStudentFullName + "','" + busStudentFatherName + "')";


    da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(sql2, con);
    da.Fill(ds1, "Students");

    con.Close();
    return true;

}
```

Business layer:

```
public bool getResponseForAddStudent(string studentName, string studentfathername)
{
    bool var = access.AddStudent(studentName, studentfathername);
    return var;
}
```

Presentation layer:

```
private void AddStudentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string studentName = StudentNameBox.Text;
    string studentfathername = StdFatherNameBox.Text;

    bool var = _busGeneral.getResponseForLogin(studentName, studentfathername);

    if (var)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Student Added");
    }
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Sorry");
    }
}
```

Comment: If your problem is with your Insert query, then why show us all the rest? And, what, exactly, is the problem with the INSERT query? You can't expect us to guess.

Comment: please format your code so that it's more readable

Comment: Spaces in column names ; proper way: [my column name]

Answer (score 0):

Your Sql isn't valid, when columns have spaces in their name need to surround with square brackets:  
`INSERT INTO Students (Student Full Name,Student Father Name)` 

instead needs to be 
`INSERT INTO Students ([Student Full Name],[Student Father Name])`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are attempting to do, there are a number of issues with your code in addition to the brackets problem.

Firstly, you are closing the connection before performing the last DataAdapter.Fill operation.
And since you want to insert a record before (re)filling the DataAdapter with student data, you must first issue a ExecuteNonQuery statement using a SqlCeCommand object. Also, to avoid injection attacks and other problems you should ALWAYS use parameterized queries. I would also advise wrapping the code with try...catch to handle errors.

Here is what I think you are trying to achieve with the insert operation (I have only desk-checked the syntax):

```
//    con.Close(); 
// string busStudentFullName;
SqlCeCommand cmd = db.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Students ([Student Full Name],[Student Father Name]) Values(@FullName, @DadsName)";
cmd.AddParameter("@FullName", busStudentFullName);
cmd.AddParameter("@DadsName", busStudentFatherName);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

At this point you can fill the DataAdapter with student rows including the newly inserted one.

Comment: Sir im using same format as i was doing abaove its updating and comparing but its not inserting.